# I get the error: Mysql No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: mysql

I have an website in an online host, when i go to the website, it says:

> MySQL No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

The website does work on **localhost**, but not on the **online host**, how do I fix it?

Comment: A quick google search can answer your question without you having to take the time to ask it again - https://stackoverflow.com/a/22736788/8260579

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736396/mysql-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it)

Comment: I read those, they are either using localhost or have unrelated problems

Answer (score 0):

there could be many reasons

if you are trying to connect to that machine for the first time then check you have given permission for allowing remote host connection.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

and then flushing privileges

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

if you have connected before then possible firewall blockage in your network.

Comment: When i try to grant, it says : #1045 - Access denied for user 'a29423_jared'@'%' (using password: YES)

Comment: maybe you are not having root access to the mysql database and execute this query by connecting to that perticular mysql via localhost (that includes going to remote machine and connect via localhost) insted of using ip address

because you won't be having permission sometimes via ip even if it's root