# MySQL: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it C#

Tags: c#, mysql

So I made a program that connects to my MySQL database that is hosted on my PC.
Connecting via localhost works, but I want to connect to the database using my external IP, but it just gives me this error.

I have already port-forwarded the ports 80, 443 and 3306 that I have set for the website and database.
The ports are also allowed in the firewall so I can't see the problem.

If anyone has any Idea on how to fix this please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you start your MySQL server?

Comment: Did you amend the user account to be allowed to connect from a remote location?

Comment: the error means that there is no software listening on the port you are trying to connect. So (probably) firewall or NAT was not configured properly. you may try with a `port scanner` tool. Where is client that is trying to connect to the external IP ?

Comment: I did start the MySQL server and I did make another user that has all access from anywhere.

Comment: I used the port scanner now and it showed this: https://imgur.com/a/H0KXk3o
And also the client is a friend from another country.

Comment: Then is has to be a firewall issue. Basically that message say I got NO response from a connection attempt. So either the firewall is closed or the server is not started or you are using the wrong Port number, or the wrong IP Address

Comment: So I double checked the IP and port (https://prnt.sc/xyvfee) and made sure it was the correct one but I don't see the problem in the firewall either because I opened ports 80,443, 3306 inbound and outbound (https://prnt.sc/xyvixs  |   https://prnt.sc/xyvkg1)

Comment: SQL Server by default has the remote connections disabled, could be a similar issue in MySQL?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mysql No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736396/mysql-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it)

Comment: @Cleptus I tried that and it doesn't work but I also made sure that it is even possible to access phpmyadmin via my external IP address and it is so I still don't even know what the problem is.

Comment: Also if it helps this is my connection string
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("datasource=89.143.161.185;port=3306;username=Mato;password=S**************;");

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are getting the password wrong in the connection string. Have you set a password?

Comment: I did set a username and password (that isn't the default root), but as I said it works with the username and password via localhost sooo.