# Our website PHP showing "Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]"

Tags: php, html

I got our website's code from a dev a long ago, and when I tried to open php file in XAMPP, we got this error:

[image: Error]

I am familiar with HTML but not PHP.

Comment: you'd need to make your question clearer. Maybe provide the data base php connection code

Comment: should i provide the index one?

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736396/mysql-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i think your database is another server and website is another server means website and database is not same server . go to phpmyadmin and add new user with host % .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).