# fatal error using php language, help me please

Tags: php

Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it in C:\xampp1\htdocs\phplogin\connection.php:6 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp1\htdocs\phplogin\connection.php(6): mysqli->__construct('localhost', 'root', Object(SensitiveParameterValue), 'db2', 3307) #1 C:\xampp1\htdocs\phplogin\index.php(2): include('C:\xampp1\htdoc...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp1\htdocs\phplogin\connection.php on line 6

fix the error so that i  could run the code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mysql No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736396/mysql-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it). Reconfigure your MySQL instance to accept the external connection. We can't fix your MySQL instance for you, you need to do that yourself.